# How to pre-populate user's contact id field on communities using lwc when a page loads

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, experience-cloud

Is there any way to pre-populate the current logged in user's contact in a lookup field in communities using LWC

HTML

```
<lightning-record-edit-form  object-api-name="CustomObj__c"> 
<lightning-input-field  field-name="CustomField__c"  onchange={nameHandler}
 </lightning-input-field>             
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getUserInfo from '@salesforce/apex/UserDetails.getUserInfo';
import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';

export default class LwcUserDetail extends LightningElement {

    @wire(getUserInfo, { userId: Id }) 
    userData;
}
```

Currently I have implemented this but not sure how to proceed

Comment: Yes. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @sfdcfox updated the answer. I am not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the wired apex code to get the user's contact Id, here is an example code.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Id getCommUserContactId(Id userId) {
    User u = [SELECT contactId FROM User WHERE id = :userId];
    return u.ContactId;
}
```

Comment: thanks @rahul also how can I also display the associated account related to the community user

Comment: @code234 You can query the related fields like Contact.AccountId in the same query.